# cout in windows application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, cout

It is very useful to debug application using `cout`. But how to deal with this in windows MFC application? Writing to stream is very convinient since you can write most types to it without headache. I could use `OutputDebugString` to create console, but that is only for strings.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You can make `cout` write its output to `OutputDebugString`, for example. A simple search for `outputdebugstring cout` yielded, among others, this hit: http://blog.tomaka17.com/2011/07/redirecting-cerr-and-clog-to-outputdebugstring/

Comment: Or stream to a string stream and send that to Debug output... Or consider a "proper" logging library

Comment: The easiest why would be to write a custom buffer that dumps to `OutputDebugString` on `sync` and tie that to either a custom stream or one of the standard streams.